# Found @client directives in a query but no ApolloClient resolvers were specified

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

OS: Windows 10 Pro
apollo-client: 2.6.3 
apollo-boost: 0.1.16

Can anyone explain why I'm getting the following error message?:

> Found @client directives in a query but no ApolloClient resolvers were
>   specified. This means ApolloClient local resolver handling has been
>   disabled, and @client directives will be passed through to your link
>   chain.

when I've defined my ApolloClient as follows:

```html
return new ApolloClient({
    uri: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? endpoint : prodEndpoint,
    request: operation => {
      operation.setContext({
        fetchOptions: {
          credentials: 'include',
        },
        headers: { cookie: headers && headers.cookie },
      });
    },
    // local data
    clientState: {
      resolvers: {
        Mutation: {
          toggleCart(_, variables, { cache }) {
            // Read the cartOpen value from the cache
            const { cartOpen } = cache.readQuery({
              query: LOCAL_STATE_QUERY,
            });
            // Write the cart State to the opposite
            const data = {
              data: { cartOpen: !cartOpen },
            };
            cache.writeData(data);
            return data;
          },
        },
      },
      defaults: {
        cartOpen: false,
      },
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/local-state/):

> If you're interested in integrating local state handling capabilities with Apollo Client < 2.5, please refer to our (now deprecated) apollo-link-state project. As of Apollo Client 2.5, local state handling is baked into the core, which means it is no longer necessary to use  apollo-link-state

The `clientState` config option was only used with `apollo-link-state`. You need to add the resolvers directly to the config as shown in the docs:

```
new ApolloClient({
  uri: '/graphql',
  resolvers: { ... },
})
```

Also note that there is no `defaults` option anymore -- the cache should be initialized by calling `writeData` directly on the cache instance (see [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/local-state/#initializing-the-cache)).

I would suggest going through the latest docs and avoiding any examples from external sources (like existing repos or tutorials) since these may be outdated.

Note: As of version 3.0, `writeData` was removed in favor of `writeFragment` and `writeQuery`.

Comment: I didn't understand something into the apollo documentation : where does local variable come from ? link: local.concat(http) => https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/basics/local-state/

Comment: @JoeAllen the documentation example is out-of-date -- there is no reason to use `apollo-link-state` anymore. You would just use the HttpLink in that example.

Comment: Hey, in the docs under https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/local-state/#initializing-the-cache it says you can still use writeData to initialize the cache. Is this out of date as well?

Comment: @Spray'n'Pray you need to select the correct version of the docs in the upper left corner of the page.

Comment: I am on `apollo-client` version `2.6.8` (which is > `2.5`) and getting this error. Any additional steps required?